# How to get xcom as a PostgresOperator parameter?

Tags: airflow

I created a xcom and I would like to get the result as a PostgresOperator parameter. I tried this

```
my_task = PostgresOperator(
    task_id=‘my_task',
    postgres_conn_id=config.get(env, 'redshift_conn'),
    sql="my_task.sql",
    params={
            ‘my_parameter': {{ int(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=‘previous_task')) }}
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Ok, and it's not working I assume? What's the error message?

Comment: The error is "ti does not exist". I tried to add  `ti = context['task_instance']` but it' not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use templating when accessing xcom within an operator.

```py
my_task = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='my_task',
    postgres_conn_id=config.get(env, 'redshift_conn'),
    sql="my_task.sql",
    params={
            'my_parameter': "{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='previous_task')}}"
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Philipp - similar approach works for all operators ? I am using the same approach for BigQueryInsertJobOperator, but it's failing -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757926/passing-result-of-a-python-operator-as-a-parameter-to-bigqueryinsertjoboperator