# Passing Result of a Python Operator as a parameter to BigQueryInsertJobOperator

Tags: airflow

I have a python operator and BigQueryInsertJobOperator in my DAG. The result returned by the python operator should be passed to BigQueryInsertJobOperator in the params field.

Below is the script I am running.

```
def get_columns():
    field = "name"
    return field


with models.DAG(
        "xcom_test",
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval="0 0 * * *",
        tags=["xcom"],
)as dag:
    t1 = PythonOperator(task_id="get_columns", python_callable=get_columns, do_xcom_push=True)

    t2 = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id="bigquery_insert",
        project_id=project_id,
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": "{% include 'xcom_query.sql' %}",
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
        },
        force_rerun=True,
        provide_context=True,
        params={
            "columns": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_columns') }}",
            "project_id": project_id
        },
    )
```

The xcom_query.sql looks below

```
INSERT INTO `{{ params.project_id }}.test.xcom_test`
    {{  params.columns }}
select 'Andrew' from `{{ params.project_id }}.test.xcom_test`
```

While running this, the columns params are converted to a string and hence resulting in an error. Below is how the query was converted.

```
 INSERT INTO `project.test.xcom_test`
  {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_columns') }}
 select 'Andrew' from `project.test.xcom_test`
```

Any idea what am I missing ?

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68024013/2838867 - according to this post the operator doesn't support params and you should use user_defined_macros instead.

Comment: In my case, the values to pass to BigQueryInsertJob operator is generated by another task, hence user_defined macros don't help..

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why my dag is failing.

The "params" field for BigQueryInsertJobOperator is not a templatized field and hence calling "task_instance.xcom_pull" will not work this way.

But instead, you can directly access the  'task_instance' variable from jinja template.

```
INSERT INTO `{{ params.project_id }}.test.xcom_test`
    ({{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_columns') }})
select
'Andrew' from `{{ params.project_id }}.test.xcom_test`
```

https://marclamberti.com/blog/templates-macros-apache-airflow/ - This article explains how to identifies template parameters in airflow